# Pycharm can't recognize Flask

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am writing a flask application with PyCharm. But Pycharm couldn't recognize Flask module. Flask installed globally on my computer as seen on screenshot. I tried virtualenv also but nothing change. Still can't find Flask. I can run Flask anywhere except Pycharm succesfully. My operating system is Windows by the way.

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ImportError: No module named flask

Comment: If u installed it globally, then u can execute `flask` command anywhere, right? try and see it it works, it it does, run `which flask` and add the output to question

Comment: I can run Flask anywhere except Pycharm succesfully. My operating system is Windows by the way. What is the equivalent of "which" command in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your file from `flask.py` to something else and it will work. Naming your file `flask.py` causes Python to look in your file for the `Flask` class, and it fails.

Comment: My file name is site.py not flask.py

Answer (score 0):

Naming a file `site.py` causes this issue.

It looks like a module named "site" is involved in importing the installed libraries, so by creating a module of the same name I prevent flask from being discovered.

Renaming my file from `site.py` to something else fixed the issue for me.